# Problem while printing the php code in pdf file using html2ps/pdf

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

I am trying to print my code that has both Html and php. I am using html2ps/pdf Api for this purpose. But when i try to print the php code it prints the code as it is if any one can help me how i can generate pdf using php. Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few HTML to PDF converters. If you are using PHP that should generate HTML, you need to be sure that the PHP file is run through the PHP engine first before the PDF generator uses it, otherwise it will only show the raw code.

Comment: if you can suggest me about any other library that i can use for html to pdf.

Comment: you can check out here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php